# Planethoster Svelte deployment

Tags: deployment, svelte, cpanel

I have web site @planethoster with cPanel and simple Svelte app, how can i deploy it ?

I copy all files after npm run build but i have white page.

It's my first Svelte project and i'm not familiar with node @planethoster

Answer (score 0):

Finally done, you need to build with static adapter ([instructions here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static)) and remove / before assets in css and js link :

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/index-O5cbZqWz.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="assets/index-nyqg60wZ.css">
```

instead of :

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index-O5cbZqWz.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/assets/index-nyqg60wZ.css">
```